# Data Exchange Framework 1.4.1 map CRM Boolean to Sitecore Checkbox

Tags: data-exchange-framework

I'm trying to map a Dynamic Boolean to a Sitecore Checkbox.

The raw value read is "True" but i need to convert to 1

Any tips?

[image: raw value]

Update:
Crm Value Accessor Set

[image: CRM]

Sitecore Value Accessor Set

[image: Sitecore]

Mapping

[image]

Comment: can you post information regarding your configuration/implementation? This might be a field mapping issue

Comment: @josedbaez updated the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use **Field Value Transformer for Write** on **Sitecore Value Accessor Set**.
This approach allows you to create a single solution not only for CRM and also for all providers where the source value is Boolean and you need to convert it to Sitecore Checkbox type.

Before to run a writer for Sitecore Field Value Writer transformer converts its value to a right format.

- Change field ***IsCommentsEnabled*** to Sitecore checkbox type.

[image]

**The Reader**

```
public class BoolToSitecoreCheckboxValueReader : IValueReader
{
    public virtual CanReadResult CanRead(object source, DataAccessContext context)
    {
        if (source is bool)
        {
            return CanReadResult.PositiveResult();
        }

        return CanReadResult.NegativeResult();
    }

    public virtual ReadResult Read(object source, DataAccessContext context)
    {
        if (source is bool value)
        {
            return ReadResult.PositiveResult(value ? "1" : "0", DateTime.Now);
        }

        return ReadResult.NegativeResult(DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

**The Converter**

```
[SupportedIds("[YOUR TEMPLATE ID]")]
public class BoolToSitecoreCheckboxReaderConverter : BaseItemModelConverter<IValueReader>
{
    public BoolToSitecoreCheckboxReaderConverter(IItemModelRepository repository) : base(repository)
    {
    }

    public override IValueReader Convert(ItemModel source)
    {
        return new BoolToSitecoreCheckboxValueReader();
    }
}
```

- Create a template where base template is **Value Reader**.

[image]

- Set Converter Type

[image]

- Add created reader under existed Tenant under the Value Readers folder

Comment: i'm missing some key points.
Do i need to create a template like in the previus answer?

Comment: Sure. Sorry I thought the hint  [YOUR TEMPLATE ID] would help.

Comment: So just to recap i create a new template (**bool to check**) that has **Value Reader** as Base Template.

Then i create a new value reader provider based on the previus template (**bool to check provider**).

Setting the converter Type to **BoolToSitecoreCheckBoxReaderConverter**.

Then on Data Access Sitecore i need to add\edit **Is Comment Enable** and set the field value transformer for write to: **bool to check provider**.

Comment: I updated my answer. Do not forget to use your template id as supported id. Yes in Field Value Transformer for Write select created Reader.

Comment: i've redo the whole process twice: the ctor of BoolToSitecoreCheckboxReaderConverter get hitted but the convert isn't.
i don't get what i'm missing

Comment: Probably [SupportedIds("[YOUR TEMPLATE ID]")]. Check it. It is string template id.

Answer (score 5):

You need to create **Value Reader Converter**:

```
public class BoolToCheckboxValueReaderConverter : BaseItemModelConverter<ItemModel, IValueReader>
    {
        private BoolToCheckboxFieldReader _reader = (BoolToCheckboxFieldReader)null;
        private static readonly Guid TemplateId = Guid.Parse("{C3C9E93C-F197-4FBD-820D-DCB565707AF7}");
        public BoolToCheckboxValueReaderConverter(IItemModelRepository repository)
      : base(repository)
        {
            this.SupportedTemplateIds.Add(TemplateId);
        }

        public override bool CanConvert(ItemModel source)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override IValueReader Convert(ItemModel source)
        {
            if (source == null)
            {
                Sitecore.DataExchange.Context.Logger.Error("Cannot convert null item to value reader. (converter: {0})", (object)this.GetType().FullName);
                return (IValueReader)null;
            }
            if (!this.CanConvert(source))
            {
                Sitecore.DataExchange.Context.Logger.Error("Cannot convert item to value reader. (item: {0}, converter: {1})", (object)source.GetItemId(), (object)this.GetType().FullName);
                return (IValueReader)null;

            }

            if (_reader == null)
                _reader = new BoolToCheckboxFieldReader(ItemModelRepository);
            return (IValueReader)_reader;
        }
    }
```

**BoolToCheckboxFieldReader** source code:

```
public class BoolToCheckboxFieldReader : IBaseValueReader
    {
        public string AttributeName { get; set; }
        public IItemModelRepository Repository { get; private set; }
        public BoolToCheckboxFieldReader(IItemModelRepository repository)
        {
            Repository = repository;
        }

        public CanReadResult CanRead(object source, DataAccessContext context)
        {
            return new CanReadResult()
            {
                CanReadValue = true
            };
        }

        public ReadResult Read(object source, DataAccessContext context)
        {
            object result = (object)null;

            var sourceObject = source as Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity;
            if (sourceObject != null)
            {
                object value;
                if (sourceObject.Attributes.TryGetValue(AttributeName, out value))
                {

                    if (value is bool)
                    {
                        var searchObject = (bool)value;
                        return new ReadResult(DateTime.UtcNow)
                        {
                            WasValueRead = true,
                            ReadValue = searchObject ? "1" : "0"
                        };
                    }
                }

            }

            return new ReadResult(DateTime.UtcNow)
            {
                WasValueRead = true,
                ReadValue = "0"
            };
        }
    }
```

**IBaseValueReader** source code:

```
public interface IBaseValueReader : IValueReader
    {
        string AttributeName { get; set; }
    }
```

In Sitecore you need to create your Value Reader template and set to "Base templates" Value Reader OOTB template:

[image]

After that you need to create **Bool To Checkbox Value Reader** item based on **Bool To Checkbox Value Reader template**:

[image]

Under `/sitecore/system/Data Exchange/Data Exchange/Data Access/Value Accessor Sets` you need to find your Entity Attribute Value Accessor, which you want to convert, and set Value Reader field (Value Access section) to **Value Readers/Providers/Dynamics CRM/Bool To Checkbox Value Reader** item.

Try to run your batch and check converted value.

Comment: This answer is not wrong, but Vlad's answer is more in the spirit of the product. Andrei's solution involves duplicating code that already exists (the ability to read an attribute value from an entity). Vlad's answer uses a feature designed for this very requirement (it lets you convert the value after it is ready but before it is written).