# How do I convert a string into a checkbox with Data Exchange Framework?

Tags: data-exchange-framework

Sitecore 9.0.2, DEF 2.0.1

As part of my data import, I need to bring in a **Status** column that contains two possible values:

- Active
- Inactive

I want to represent these as a checkbox field in Sitecore, but I can't figure out how to convert them.

I found [this question from an older version of DEF](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/9667/data-exchange-framework-1-4-1-map-crm-boolean-to-sitecore-checkbox), but the interface for `IValueReaders` has changed requires a different return value for the conversion process.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually a built-in value reader for this: the [Description to Code Value Reader](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/def/20/data-exchange-framework/en/description-to-code-value-reader.html). It works by defining a set of code definitions which map a "code" (`int`) to a "description" (`string`). To use it:

## Create your code definition set and code definitions

1. In your Data Exchange tenant under the **Tenant Settings/Common** folder, add a new **Code Definition Sets Root** folder

   - Template Path: /sitecore/templates/Data Exchange/Framework/Code Definitions/Code Definition Sets Root
   - Template ID: {88A5FB53-E56B-404F-BA17-8F55013A03CC}
2. Add a **Code Definition Set** to that folder
3. Add **Code Definition**s to the **Code Definition Set**

   - Active

     - **Item Name**: Active
     - **Value**: 1
   - Inactive

     - **Item Name**: Inactive
     - **Value**: 0

## Add the value reader and use it

1. In your Data Exchange tenant under the **Data Access/Value Readers/Common** folder, add a new **Description to Code Value Reader**
2. In the **Code Definition Set** field, select your recently-created Code Definition Set
3. In the **Value Mapping** item for the field, set the **Source Value Transformer** field to your new value reader